# datareader mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Ok I have a stored procedure and I would like to build an array of each of the result sets.

An array of array so to speak.

My stored procedure when i run through mysql workbench returns the correct result.

It works by looping through each collection correctly. However after the last result it comes back to results and then throws an error which the exeception catches.

Exception message is just SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error.

If seems next result goes to far.

How can i get around this. The error occurs when trying to read results that dont exist. A collection maybe there but it may have no rows so a row count would not get around it as in a later point in code i need to know where array maps to which object i.e. $image = result[0], $events = $result[1];

if i did a row count $result[0] could end being set to events.

```
public static function getHomePageContent()
{
    $results = array();

    try{
        $connection = Yii::app()->db;
        $command = $connection->createCommand("CALL get_homepage_content()");


        $dataReader = $command->query();
        $dataReader->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        do {                   
                $results[] =  $dataReader->readAll();

        } while ($dataReader->nextResult());

        $dataReader->close();
    }

    catch(Exception $e){
        Yii::log('', CLogger::LEVEL_ERROR, $e->getMessage());
    }

    $connection->setActive(false);

    return $results;
}
```

Stored Procedure is

```
BEGIN

SET @slideshow_visible := 1;
SET @image_approved :=1;
SET @image_visible  :=1;
SET @image_format_type :='image';
SET @video_format_type :='video';

/* Main Slideshow Details */
SELECT title, button_url, title_text, alt_text, image_path, caption
FROM slideshow 
WHERE visible = @slideshow_visible
ORDER BY slideshow.order ASC;

/* News Section */
SELECT p1.*,wm2.meta_value
FROM warring_blogw.wp_posts p1
LEFT JOIN
      warring_blogw.wp_postmeta wm1
      ON (
              wm1.post_id = p1.id
              AND wm1.meta_value IS NOT NULL
              AND wm1.meta_key = "_thumbnail_id"
      )
LEFT JOIN
      warring_blogw.wp_postmeta wm2
      ON (
              wm1.meta_value = wm2.post_id
              AND wm2.meta_key = "_wp_attached_file"
              AND wm2.meta_value IS NOT NULL
      )         
/*LEFT JOIN 
     warring_blogw.wp_usermeta wm3
         ON(
                wm3.user_id = p1.post_author
            )*/
WHERE
      p1.post_status="publish"
      AND p1.post_type="post";

/* Photos */
SELECT im.title,im.alias_title, im.description, im.thumbnail_image_small, im.hits 
FROM image im
WHERE im.approved = @image_approved AND im.visible = @image_visible AND im.format_type = @image_format_type;


SELECT * from event;
```

its always on the last result i get the error - even if i use a while loop or a do while the error occurs on fetchall

Answer (score 0):

To return a result set, instead of the exception, you could add the following towards the top your stored procedure:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        SELECT 'SQLEXCEPTION raised' AS errmsg;
```

Of course, you should probably fix the fact that the exception is being thrown in the first place.  Perhaps you would want to post the stored procedure's contents?